# What operation does a beam splitter apply?

Tags: optics, terminology

What is the unitary matrix equivalent to the operation of a beam splitter?

I'm asking because I've seen different matrices used and was wondering if the term is just ambiguous or if there's an agreed upon meaning.

The ["quantum chesire cat" paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.0631) treats beam splitters as a square-root-of-not-with-extra-phase-factor
$$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ i & 1 \end{bmatrix} \, .$$

On the other hand, the ["QuVis" visualization project](http://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/physics/quvis/embed_item_3.php?anim_id=2&file_sys=index) says that the correct matrix is the Hadamard gate
$$H = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \, .$$

The difference between these two matters. For example, $H^2 = I$ but $A^2 \propto X$. Also, $HZH = X$ but $AZA = A^2 e^{i \pi Z/2}$. Which operation should I be thinking of, when an article says "beam splitter"?

Comment: "unitary matrix equivalent to the operation of a beam splitter": On what? On the creation operators? -- Other than that, both matrices are equivalent up to a multiplication from left and right with $\mathrm{diag}(1,-i)$, which depends on how you define your modes (or whatever else your matrices act on).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I mean: if I want to emulate a beam splitter in a quantum computer, which gates should I use.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch For example, if I am representing the position of the photon as a qubit where OFF=bottom-path and ON=top-path and I'm told to place a -1 phase shift on the top path, then whether I used an H or sqrt(X) gate will affect the resulting qubit state in a measurable way.

Comment: I think the distinction is between a polarizing (the first) and non-polarizing (the second) beam splitter but I'll have to look up some references.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Isn't a polarizing beam splitter a beam splitter that sends horizontally polarized light one way and vertically polarized light the other? That's more like a controlled-not, because it involves two qubits (the polarization and the path).

Comment: @Strilanc I think you should first make clear to yourself and to us what these matrices mean. Otherwise, there is no way we can agree on the *difference* between those two matrices. -- My interpretation is that you are talking about building a linear optical quantum computer with a dual rail encoding of a qubit (i.e., one photon in one of two paths), you insert a beam splitter, and you want to know the gate action in the quantum computer. -- But unless you clearly explain what these matrices describe these are just wild guesses.

Comment: @Strilanc You can't do CNOTs with linear optics.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch You can do CNOTs in some special cases. For example, a half-wave plate placed on the top path of an interferometer can toggle the polarization of a photon conditioned on the path.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Take [this quantum circuit simulator](https://jsfiddle.net/c4f5z73v/2/embedded/result/), and use it to emulate a beam splitter. The matrices are operations to apply to a qubit. A qubit is a two level quantum system, the matrices are 2x2, so they can be applied to that system. For example, the hadamard gate transitions and OFF qubit into an (ON+OFF)/sqrt(2) qubit.

Comment: This article can help you undersatand two matrix difference in view of group thoery.
http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.33.4033

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both operations are equivalent, up to a local phase in the second mode. In particular, if you shift the second basis vector's phase by $i$, then you will turn $H$ into $A$. In a beam splitter this is perfectly natural, because the phases of the output modes are not particularly well defined, and you can always model the difference between the two operations as an extra phase plate on one of the output modes. In any case, the phase difference between the two modes is not an experimental observable unless you bring the two modes together and interfere them, in which case you will want to introduce a variable phase delay between them to control the interference. This extra controlled phase delay will eat up this static par difference.

Comment: So it really is an ambiguous shorthand for "some operation that mixes the states, and the details should be clear in context"? Huh.. Thanks.

Comment: Sort of. It's more like "a linear transformation between the input and output mode operators which gives equal weight to both inputs on both outputs, with an added phase to ensure that operation is unitary, and for which the details depend on the context and should be worked out in specifics on a case by case basis", though really changing conventions doesn't really affect anything much.